# Which are the IP-Ranges for Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I´m being asked for my site´s IP Ranges and it is hosted in Elastic Beanstalk (US East (N.Virginia)). Can somebody tell me which are them currently, or where to look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related to:

[Where does Amazon publish the range of IP addresses used for EC2 instances by region?](http://serverfault.com/questions/223305/where-does-amazon-publish-the-range-of-ip-addresses-used-for-ec2-instances-by-re)